# Nearest locations to multiple routes

Tags: r, spatial, r-sf

I'd like to get the nearest location from each of a list of routes and the distance from the route to the place.  I think I can do this via SF but am not sure how.  In the sample data there are 19 separate routes.

```
install.packages("sf")
install.packages("sfheaders")
library(sf)

routeData <-  read.csv("https://www.dropbox.com/s/vtj8wvcqxj52pbl/SpainActivityRoutes.csv?dl=1")

# Convert routes to SF
sfheaders::sf_multipolygon(
  obj = spainActivityRoutes
  , multipolygon_id = "id"
  , x = "lon"
  , y = "lat"
)

# Read in locations
locations <- data.frame(id = c(1,2,3),
                        place = c('Alcudia', 'Puerto de Pollensa', 'Alaro'),
                        latitude = c(39.85327712, 39.9024565, 39.704459175469395),
                        longitude = c(3.123974802, 3.080426926, 2.7919874776545694))
```

Comment: convert your `locations` into an `sf` object, set the CRS on both, and then use `sf::st_nearest_feature()` to get the nearest location, then `sf::st_distance()` to calculate the distance.

Comment: If these are routes, as in *lines*, you shouldn't be converting them to MULTIPOLYGON. You need to group by `id` and create LINESTRING features. Full answer maybe later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting with the data:

```
routeData <-  read.csv("https://www.dropbox.com/s/vtj8wvcqxj52pbl/SpainActivityRoutes.csv?dl=1")
```

split on id, apply a function to create linestring objects, join the list of linestrings using `st_sfc` to make a spatial vector. Assume these are "GPS" coordinates with EPSG code 4326:

```
routes = do.call(st_sfc, lapply(split(routeData, routeData$id) , function(d){st_linestring(cbind(d$lon, d$lat))}))
st_crs(routes)=4326
```

Convert points data frame to spatial points data frame with same coordinate system:

```
pts = st_as_sf(locations, coords=c("longitude","latitude"), crs=4326)
```

Now we can get the nearest route to each point:

```
> nearf = st_nearest_feature(pts, routes)
> nearf
[1]  1 15 19
```

So the first point is nearest to route 1, the second point route 15, the third point route 19. Now the distances we get by computing the distance from each point in turn to each of those route lines in turn by using `st_distance` with `by_element=TRUE` (otherwise it computes the distances from all points to all three routes as a matrix):

```
> st_distance(pts, routes[st_nearest_feature(pts, routes)], by_element=TRUE)
Units: [m]
[1]  7.888465 27.046029 44.175458
```

If you want the point on the route nearest to the point data then use `st_nearest_points` with `pairwise=TRUE`:

```
> st_nearest_points(pts, routes[st_nearest_feature(pts, routes)], pairwise=TRUE)
Geometry set for 3 features 
Geometry type: LINESTRING
Dimension:     XY
Bounding box:  xmin: 2.791987 ymin: 39.70412 xmax: 3.124058 ymax: 39.90256
Geodetic CRS:  WGS 84
LINESTRING (3.123975 39.85328, 3.124058 39.85331)
LINESTRING (3.080427 39.90246, 3.080143 39.90256)
LINESTRING (2.791987 39.70446, 2.792247 39.70412)
```

which returns 2-point lines from the test point to the line. You can use functions like `st_cast(...,"POINT")` to split those into points and get the locations as points.

Comment: This is brilliant @Spacedman.  With the line that gets the distance from the 3 locations to the nearest route, is it possible to get the distances from the 19 routes to the nearest location?

Comment: I can see that nearestLocations = st_nearest_feature(routes, pts) get the nearest locations to the 19 routes.

Comment: you can replace the `do.call(...)` with `sfheaders::sf_linestring()`, in exactly the same way @Chris used `sfheaders::sf_multipolygon()`